# YouTube downloader using MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll, mfc

I am creating a YouTube downloader type application in MFC.
I have a textbox, and add button and a `CListCtrl`.
My problem is how to add the textbox URL in the `CListCtrl` when clicking on the add button?

Comment: i just want to add textbox text into ClistCtrl by clicking Add button,using MFC.

Comment: No one know the Answer ? What a Shame?

Comment: [CListCtrl::InsertItem()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b9s12fc(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have probably bound all controls to variables via DDX (textbox via value, clistctrl via control). Your code looks probably like this:

```
void CYouTubeDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_URLTEXTBOX, m_strURL);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_URLLIST, m_ListCtrl);
}
```

Read more about DDX here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwz5tb1x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

The Add button triggers a method when clicked via the message map functionality.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CYouTubeDialog, CDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_ADDBUTTON, OnBnClickedAdd)
END_MESSAGE_MAP( )
```

Read more about message maps here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x0cx6b1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

This method triggered adds the content of the text edit to the list ctrl and clears the content:

```
CYouTubeDialog::OnBnClickedAdd()
{
    UpdateData(true);
    m_ListCtrl.InsertItem(0, m_strURL);  
    m_strURL.Empty();
    UpdateData(false);
}
```

I do not know how your ListCtrl looks like (columns etc), you can read more about them here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bycfwcsh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

I hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: oops i forgot to say that with the URL text i also want to add progressbar in each column ! URL text is already added successfully thanls but now how to add progressbar controll ?

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately, I have never used the ProgressBarCtrl, especially not in a CListCtrl. But a quick look via Google showed me, that there is already a solution existing for progress bars in CListCtrls: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1342/Adding-progress-bars-to-a-list-control ... Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much Chrislnked